# How do you specify your Content Type in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, content-type, xhtml-1.0-strict

I'm specifying my doctype as xhtml strict, but it's being sent over the wire as a content type of text/html.  I'd like to specify that the content type is application/xhtml+xm, but I can't figure out where, or if, I can configure this from within my application

Comment: BTW, after doing this, just about every browser took a dump on me.  So I left it the way it was being sent.  Web standards, you gotta hate 'em.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can specify it in the @ page attributes section, like this:

```
<%@ Page ContentType="application/xhtml+xm" %>
```

...more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Can't do it from the master?  Urgh.

Comment: Sadly, it does not appear so.

Comment: I guess you could set it via Response but that might get a bet sketchy in terms of functionality

Comment: Yeah, Response would be the only from from the master page.

Comment: Classic example of [why link-only answers are a bad idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). The answer didn't actually answer the question unless you followed the link. The link died, making the answer completely useless. I've fixed it -- by fixing the link (for now), but more importantly by actually putting the answer **in** the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In your code behind file, during the Page_Load event, try addind the following code:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application/xhtml+xm"
```

Comment: That's the property you want, but you'll probably want to set it sooner than load (maybe Pre_Init)

Answer (score 0):

=========aspx===============

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"
Inherits="_Default" %>


<asp:literal runat="server" id="dt"></asp:literal>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
```

==============code behind=========

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.dt.Text= "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
Transitional//EN\"
\"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">";

}
```

Comment: Your code is not related to the question, but it helped me- see http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2011/09/23/change-doctype-dynamically.aspx